# XM List command is Not working

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, xen

I have created a local repository to install Xen on Centos -6.4 . I have followed the steps to install and download the xen dependecies from this link 
 http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.2-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization

When I install from local repository it has installed successfully with no errors. But When I rebooted it is not able to boot completely but i am able to login in that machine. I have started the Xend service manually but when I am given xm list command I am getting this error :

Error: Unable to connect to xend: No such file or directory. Is xend running?

I am not able to resolve this . Kindly help me how can i resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified if Xend is running.

```
service xend status
```

(or)

```
ps -ef|grep xend
```

also verify

```
service libvirtd status
```